# TypeScript + react-native-sqlite-storage => error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transaction'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using SQLite through [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) and trying to use TypeScript.

But TypeScript can't find some of the types. The code causing trouble:

```
db.transaction((tx: Transaction) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM movies', [], (tx: Transaction, results: ResultSet) => {
    console.log("Query completed");
  });
});
```

TypeScript errors:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --alwaysStrict --skipLibCheck
App.tsx:18:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transaction'.

18    db.transaction((tx: Transaction) => {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~

App.tsx:19:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Transaction'.

19       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM movies', [], (tx: Transaction, results: ResultSet) => {
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~

App.tsx:19:76 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ResultSet'.

19       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM movies', [], (tx: Transaction, results: ResultSet) => {
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~
```

This is crazy because the `Transaction` interface is defined [here in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native-sqlite-storage/index.d.ts#L63), so it should be found. The types for the other functions provided by react-native-sqlite-storage are properly found.

**What's happening? How is it possible that some types are found and some other, from the same types file?**

To reproduce the problem, all my project files are [here](https://gist.github.com/vmarquet/06b6f3e9dc1bbf4df4fc3f38cf063c9c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing types are members of the `react-native-sqlite-storage` module, and you've imported the entire module under the name `SQLite`:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'
```

So you have to qualify the types like this:

```
db.transaction((tx: SQLite.Transaction) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM movies', [], (tx: SQLite.Transaction, results: SQLite.ResultSet) => {
    console.log("Query completed");
  });
});
```

just like you qualified `SQLite.openDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that... I'm new to TypeScript and I didn't see the namespacing thing on the tutorials.